# Getting Error in codeigniter ajax dropdown changing

Tags: codeigniter

Getting Error in codeigniter ajax dropdown changing
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
       function fun1(sid) {
            //alert(sid);
            var obj;

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                obj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            }
            obj.open("post", "https://99shopin.com/register/getcity?val=" + sid, true);
            obj.send();
            obj.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (obj.readyState == 4) {

                    document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = obj.responseText;
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = "";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: where is the code for calling ajax and code for controller/method to fetch data?

Comment: where is your getcity method?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and check Is there still an error?

```
function fun1(sid){
        $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function () {
                },
                complete: function () {
                },
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('register/getcity'); ?>",
                data: ({val: sid}),
                //dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                       document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = data.responseText;
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: you didn't share your getcity() code form controller, can you share it?

Comment: Now error is gone data is coming in fire bug but not populate in dropdown div

Comment: what was the issue ?

Comment: it is saying undefined

Comment: without seeing your getcity method how can I solve your issue? AND what undefined any variable or array what?